# Full-time Freelancing for UK based client from Spain

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, tax-law, spain

I've got a freelance contract signed with an UK based customer, saying that I should do my best to devote at least 174 hours a month (that's 21 days working 8h/day).

I'm based on Spain, where I'm paying my taxes. 3 months taxes nearly equals one month's billed ammount.

Are those 174 hours a month the equivalent to a full-time commitment? Should my client be in charge of paying my taxes or I should pay them in UK (under PAYE)?

ps: I'm only working for this client.

Comment: I'm only working/billing for this client, as for the last 5 months.

Answer (score 1):

After calling Hacienda (Spanish version of HRMC), this is a completely legal and usual situation.

But, as I'm economically dependient from my customer, I've the right the ask my customer for a TRADE freelance contract ("Trababador autónomo económicamente dependiente" / "Economically dependent self-employed worker"), which my customer should sign.

It will allow/protect the freelance for the following benefits:

- Formalize a economically dependent self-employed contract in writing
- Annual break of at least 18 working days. (+ bank holidays)
- Choose your representatives.
- Compensation for damages incurred when the contract is unjustified-broken.
- Signing agreements of professional interest.
- Access to the jurisdiction of the social.

Find more information at http://infoautonomos.eleconomista.es/seguridad-social/trabajadores-autonomos-economicamente-dependientes/